# How do I access Azure application settings on the client-side in a SPA Nuxt web-app

Tags: azure, environment-variables, nuxt.js, single-page-application

I need to set an environment variable in the Azure application settings to change the api endpoint URL based on which Azure slot I'm using. So I am trying to add a "BASE_URL" setting in my configuration settings with the endpoint URL I want to use, and then in my Nuxt app, I am trying to access this using "process.env.BASE_URL", but I end up getting "undefined". The Nuxt documentation is absolutely useless as is the Azure documentation, do any of you know how to access Azure application settings in a Nuxt app? (or Vue app even?)

Thanks

Comment: Off-topic: the documentation doesn't seem to be 'absolutely useless', you just weren't able to find the correct documentation. Please refrain from comments like that.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get settings that live on the *server* from an application that runs on the *client* (browser). By default, that's not going to work.

One solution would be to implement an API that returns the setting or settings that you need on the frontend so you can call the API from the SPA and use the returning setting(s).

Another solution would be to use Azure App Configuration and access the settings from there. For examples on how to access App Configuration from JavaScript, have a look at [Azure App Configuration client library samples for JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-js/app-configuration-javascript/).

> These sample programs show how to use the JavaScript client libraries for Azure App Configuration in some common scenarios.